# Delphi int64 overflow bug in IDE

Tags: delphi

Delphi has had problems with int64.  I'm using XE7.  The following, with the 64-bit Windows target shows a problem:

```
var x : int64; 
begin 
x := 1;
repeat
  x := 3 * x;
  writeln( x);
until false;
```

When it overflows, rather than putting you on the line were the overflow occurred, it opens the system unit and is on the line

```
system procedure _IntOver;
```

This makes tracking down an int64 overflow very difficult.  Like I said, I'm using XE7 - has it been fixed in the current version?

Comment: `Project - Options - Compiling - Use debug dcu = false`? Anyway - you have `Callstack` window and can use it.

Comment: There's nothing to fix. That's as designed. Use the call stack.

Comment: Thank you - turning off debug DCU makes the IDE go to the line where the error occurred, the way it does with 32-bit integers and smaller.   --- You say they designed it that way.  Why would they design it to work differently on 64-bit integers than the way it works on 32-bit integers and smaller?

Comment: No, it is Win64 - I just double-checked to make sure.

Comment: @J... It's definitely Win64 because it is a known defect that integer overflow errors are not raised for 64 bit types in the 32 bit compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a defect, this is just how the functionality is implemented. The compiler uses helper functions in the runtime library to raise the overflow exception. That is simply how the functionality is designed.

You can use the call stack to find the line of your code that lead to the error. If you want to make the debugger break on that line of code then you should uncheck the *Use debug .dcus* option.